# How to set primary key on table in a dataset

Tags: vb.net, primary-key

Below I load a dataset, which I believe is table 0. Then I set the name of table 0 in the dataset to PickTable:

```
PickDataSet.ReadXml(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & Pickfile)
PickDataSet.Tables(0).TableName = "PickTable"
```

I'm having trouble now finding syntax to set the primary key for the PickTable. Column 0 is unique and always has a value. I need to make this the primary key.

I tried something like this:

```
PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").PrimaryKey = PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").Columns(0);
```

Comment: @TalhaShafique If you leave a comment on your edits, please put some actual information in it. An empty comment is more useful than one which looks like it contains something, but doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.PrimaryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.primarykey) property of `DataTable` expect an array of `DataColumn` objects. So you can set the first column as primary key with the following line:

```
PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").PrimaryKey = {PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").Columns(0)}

'or

PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {PickDataSet.Tables("PickTable").Columns(0)}
```

Comment: while waiting I discovered this   very similar    PickDataSet.Tables(0).PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {PickDataSet.Tables(0).Columns(0)}    only diff being the new datacolumn()       is my variant correct?

Comment: Yes you can also use this. At the end both solutions should work.

Comment: @yellow : Your and Sebastian's solution are exactly the same. When you ignore the `New DataColumn()` part the compiler will infer the type and write it for you.